# Change Font color and alignment in Excel by VBA

Tags: vba, excel, csv, vbscript

Requirement is :

I have a fixed template of EXCEL where from row 4 to row 10 (may be more in future) will be deleted and added everyday from CSV.
Now my VBS is deleting existing records from the excel and put data from CSV. which is working perfectly. After that small changes required, is it possible to make delete existing rows dynamically
i.e. today I have 10 rows so it is clearing 10, tomorrow if 20 rows come can it clears those records and insert as per input row number from CSV.

here is my existing code :

```
srccsvfile = Wscript.Arguments(0)
tgtxlsfile = Wscript.Arguments(1)

'Create Spreadsheet
'Look for an existing Excel instance.
On Error Resume Next ' Turn on the error handling flag
Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
'If not found, create a new instance.
If Err.Number = 429 Then  '> 0
  Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If

objExcel.Visible = False
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

'Import CSV into Spreadsheet
Set objWorkbookSrc = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(srccsvfile)
Set objWorksheetSrc = objWorkbookSrc.Worksheets(1)
Set objWorkbookTgt = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(tgtxlsfile)
Set objWorksheetTgt = objWorkbookTgt.Worksheets("Report")
'Adjust width of columns
Set objRange = objWorksheetSrc.UsedRange
objRange.Borders.LineStyle = 1
Set objRangeToCopy = objRange.Resize(objRange.Rows.Count - 1).offset(1)
objWorksheetTgt.Rows(4).Resize(10).Clear

objRangeToCopy.Copy objWorksheetTgt.Range("A4")

aList = Array("NOT ", "NO ", "NONE", "!")
For Each Item In aList
            For Each c In objWorksheetTgt.UsedRange
                If InStr(1, c.Value, Item) > 0 Then
                    c.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                End If
            Next
Next

'Save Spreadsheet, 51 = Excel 2007-2010
objWorkbookTgt.Save
objWorkbookTgt.Close(False)
objWorkbookSrc.Close(False)

'Release Lock on Spreadsheet
objExcel.Quit()
Set objWorksheetSrc = Nothing
Set objWorkbookSrc = Nothing
Set objWorksheetTgt = Nothing
Set objWorkbookTgt = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

Finally some finishing touch. 
Need to write these data in Excel in Font : **ABC_Font** and Size : **10**
and based on some column_name need **Center/Right**, i.e. Name and Location value Should be "**Center**" and Phone no should be "**Align Center**" and "**WrapText**" . And new line character also needed.
Is that also possible??

i tried in excel macro to get this done. and found below code, thought that it would make my script final, but its not working.

Now I need to fit below sample code in my existing above code which i attached as txt file for your reference. and i attached sample excel and csv both.

```
Range("A4:F13").Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Trebuchet MS"
        .Size = 10
    End With

Range("A4:A13").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = True
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
```

Here is my CSV

```
Name,Location,Phone,Comment1,Comment2,comment3
"ABC!","Pune",123,"Expert Value","! Easy","Popular"
"XYZ","Kol",567,"! Expert value",Easy,"!Credit"
"PQR","Mum",234,"NOT value","Value for money","Debit"
"RST","DEL",0,"Value","NO value","N/A"
"Ram","KOL",100,"NO Value","value","N/A"
"XYZ","Kol",567,"! Expert value","!Easy","!Credit"
"qwer","DEL",567,"Expert value","Easy","!Credit"
"cvbn","Pune",567,"! Expert value","!Easy","!Debit"
"rtyu","DEL",567,"! Expert value","Easy","!Credit"
"kllo","Pune",567,"Expert value","NOT Easy","!Bad"
```

This is my present output Excel screenshot

[image]

But I wanted the output like this.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, what's the question? Is it related to the formatting? Or how to delete rows?

Comment: http://help.mjtnet.com/article/19-converting-office-vba-to-vbscript

Comment: There are 2 code snippet...and 2 excel screenshot.....i have first code which output is 1st screenshot...now i have to add the 2nd code into 1st one so that my output will be like second screenshot

Comment: do not use _Select ... Selection_   use this  `With Range("A4:F13").Font`

Answer (score 0):

just copy and paste the formatting code before the save point in the main code

Comment: My code is already added in my post...what exactly you need bro?

Comment: Its not working bro... i tried this..

`code` 
With Range("A4:F13").Font
        .Name = "Trebuchet MS"
        .Size = 10
End With`code`

Answer (score 0):

Cell set  .WrapText = True   .

```
     With Range("A4:F13")
        With .Font
            .Name = "Trebuchet MS"
            .Size = 10
        End With
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = True
        .EntireRow.AutoFit
    End With
    With Range("A4:A13")
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = True
    End With
```

Comment: not working.... same as before... after changing code output excel should change font size... and its as default Calibri with 11 size